# What should I name a class for a class of students in a school?

Tags: naming-conventions

Using python (or any other language that reserves the word Class):

The model I'm using consists of subjects (for example Year 10 English, Year 11 Chemistry, year 12 IT), and classes, which correspond to timetable entries (e.g. 10ENGB - Year 10 English group B). I can't work out a suitable name for the class class.

Also, the relationship between a student and a subject is an enrolment. What would you call a relationship between a student and a class? Between a teacher and a class?

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
>   and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Answer (score 3):

This [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/class) suggests "course" or "session", among others.  The relationship between student and class can be "student_in", and between teacher and class, "teacher_of".

BTW, the better form of that quote is:

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.